# Using $injector vs. direct DI in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I am not seeing the difference (or pros/cons) to directly injecting my dependencies vs. using $injector in angularjs. Why would I do one or the other? Here is a sample of the two.

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("myService", [
        "$injector", function($injector) {

            var $http = $injector.get("$http");

            //used $injector to get $http, now get some data, etc.
        }
    ]);

angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("myService", [
        "$http", function($http) {

            //just use $http to get some data, etc.
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most cases, the second method is simple, readable and it just works, especially if you use a precompiler that writes the string values for you, e.g. [ng-annotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate):

```
angular.module("myApp")
    .factory("myService", /*@ngInject*/ function($http, $locale, $window) {
    });
```

I see no reason why you should avoid it.

The first method, using `$injector` should be reserved for specific cases, e.g. when there are too many injections (and you don't want to refactor right now) or in some specific cases in tests.

Comment: Thanks. Do you agree with @sma below that sample 1 makes unit testing easier?

Comment: @BBauer42 I would say that it's too broad a statement :) I have just finished writing a pretty big application tested with karma/jasmine and we had no problems using dependency injection (using `inject(function(...))`). However, there are cases when you need `$inject`. For instance when the injectable is just a function (not an object) and you need to mock it. In 95% of the cases dependency injection just works and it is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions work, but difference is in the code readability and extensibility.

Using the second solution you see all module's dependecies by factory definition.

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("myService", [
        "$myService", function($myService) {

        }
    ]);
```

If you injecting a whole $injector, your dependencies will be fixed. You won't be able to inject other service with consistent API.

```
angular
    .module("myApp")
    .factory("myService", [
        "$injector", function($injector) { 
            var $myService = $injector.get("myService");
        }
    ]);
```

To sum up, both solutions work, but use the first posiblity.

Answer (score 0):

It also makes unit testing much easier to use the first example.  You simply mock the injections and your dependencies are handled for you.  There are ways to get around it for the second example, but you're just making your life more difficult.